# Why is Spatie laravel-webhook-client payload empty on production server only?

Tags: json, laravel, webhooks

Using Spatie laravel-webhook-client

All is working with end point on development server (Windows) testing with Postman. Getting request, validating signature, and posting payload to queued job. All works as expected with full payload as sent from source.

Production server receives webhook, validates signature, and saves entry in webhook_calls table. But the payload entry in the table is an empty object "[]" and nothing is available in the queued job.

Why is the payload empty only on the production server?

[image: Table entries]

EDIT: Found that source content-type from AWS (SNS) is text/plain and not application/json. This was an apparent oversight by AWS many years ago. How do I handle text/plain in Laravel using the Spatie package?

Answer (score 0):

wow what a royal PITA. Amazon admitted to mistakenly making their content-type for SNS messages text/plain 10 years ago. Unfortunately, those of us just starting to use that service is finding this out by trial/error.

To solve my problem, I changed a line of code in the Spatie package:

laravel-webhook-client/src/Models/WebhookCall.php, line 23

from - `'payload' => $request->input(),`

to - `'payload' => json_decode($request->getContent(), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES),`

This worked for me. I'll have to stick with this version of Spatie in case they ever upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, in March 2023, Amazon SNS launched support for custom `Content-Type` headers for HTTP messages delivered from topics. Here's the launch post: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-sns-content-type-request-headers-http-s-notifications/

You'll have to modify the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute of your Amazon SNS subscription, setting the `headerContentType` property to `application/json`, or any other value supported. You can find all values supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy

```
{
    "healthyRetryPolicy": {
        "minDelayTarget": 1,
        "maxDelayTarget": 60,
        "numRetries": 50,
        "numNoDelayRetries": 3,
        "numMinDelayRetries": 2,
        "numMaxDelayRetries": 35,
        "backoffFunction": "exponential"
    },
    "throttlePolicy": {
        "maxReceivesPerSecond": 10
    },
    "requestPolicy": {
        "headerContentType": "application/json"
    }
}
```

You set the `DeliveryPolicy` attribute by calling either the `Subscribe` or the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` API action:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html

Alternatively, you can use AWS CloudFormation for setting this policy as well, using the `AWS::SNS::Subscription` resource.